# Recreate the Style Resource Readers group

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

2013 Enterprise

One of our client's site collections suffered the unfortunate fate of having its Style Resource Readers group deleted. For quick damage control I gave all users permissions to the master page gallery, but I want a long-term solution. I haven't been able to dig up much information about how to do this, everyone just says "don't delete it", which is sound advice to be sure, but does not help our client's situation. Short of restoring the entire site from a backup or recreating the collection and migrating the existing content to it, is there a less drastic solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go simple, if you only deleted the SP group, make up by choosing the group from another site collection and use the the check permissions to get the relevant permissions assigned (unless permission inheritance has been broken, which means you are out-of-luck).