# Restore Style Resources Readers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I've a site where this group was deleted and now i've some issue.
How can i restore this?

I know it has limited access and access to master page galery and style library but how to recreate this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do have the group in another site collection where you can look up what permissions the group have, and just create a new group with the same permissions.

Go to another site collection where you got the group intact and go to Site settings > site permissions > permission levels. From here select "Style resources reader" to see exactly what kind of permissions the group have.

Create a new group in the site where you removed the group and assign the same permission as the Style resource readers had in the other site collection.

The Style library can be found under all site content. But to find the masterpage gallery you need to use SharePoint Designer.

[Recreate the Style Resource Readers group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79879/recreate-the-style-resource-readers-group)

> Style Resource Readers
>
> Read to the Master Page Gallery and Restricted Read to the Style
>   Library. Members of this group are given Read permission to the Master
>   Page Gallery and Restricted Read permission to the Style Library. By
>   default, all authenticated users are a member of this group.

[Determine permission levels and groups in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262690%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: How to do this and where find Style library? I'm using sharepoint 2010. When i add group, i can't put limited access